# Круговой импорт Python: как справиться с ним?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, модули, импорт

Существует приложение, использующее `PyQt5`, которое состоит из главного скрипта `AsQamm.py` и собственной библиотеки `_asQamm`, в которой находятся все функции, необходимые для его работы.

Функции находятся в классах, унаследованных от класса `MainWindow`, внутри соответствующих модулей. Соответственно, каждый модуль для своей работы нуждается в импорте класса `MainWindow`, который находится в AsQamm.py.

В то же время, в конструкторе класса `MainWindow` есть методы, для вызова которых необходимы модули из `_asQamm`. В итоге - *получается порочный круг кругового импорта*, при попытке с ним справиться вылетают самые разные ошибки.

---

### Дисклеймер

Я знаю, что по-хорошему, нужно делать МВП, однако я не понимаю, как мне изложить суть проблемы, не рассказав всю суть.

---

### Структура приложения

Текущая структура приложения и комментарий представлена ниже. Вы также можете спустится ниже к списку ссылок на файлы и смотреть их код через `pastebin`:

```py
_asQamm     #Библиотека со всеми модулями, которые необходимы для осуществления функций приложения.
    |________
    |__init__.py        #На данный момент здесь отсутствуют какие-либо команды. Я пробовал перенести сюда 
    |  (пустой)         #команды импорта из AsQamm.py, но это породило другую проблему — классы из 
    |                   #модулей, находящихся в библиотеке (см. далее), не могли  
    |                   #инициализироваться, так как имя MainWindow при 
    |                   #'определении классов не определяется (ImportError: 
    |                   # name ‘MainWindow’ is not defined').
    |________
    |asQammUI.py        #Второй по важности модуль приложения. Его код является результатом работы 
    |  (ссылка ниже)    #pyuic5, здесь находится интерфейс. От класса Ui_MainWindow здесь наследуется 
    |                   #главный класс приложения MainWindow.
    |________
    |asQammFunctions.py #Внутри находится класс UIFunctions, предназначенный для осуществления действий с 
    |  (ссылка ниже)    #интерфейсом приложения без создания экземпляра, по этой причине класс не имеет 
    |                   #конструктора. Все методы этого класса работают напрямую с родительским классом 
    |                   #MainWindow. Фактически, в модуле functions я планировал размещать классы с 
    |                   #методами, для осуществления которых создавать экземпляр класса не нужно.
    |________
    |asQammResources.py #RCC, и так понятно, зачем он нужен. Не содержит никакого дополнительно 
    |  (ссылка ниже)    #написанного мной кода, подгружается в начале AsQamm.py. Прикрепил в неконверт. 
    |                   #виде, конвертируйте командой 
    |                   # `pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o _asQamm\asQammResources.py`.
    |________
    |asQammUsers.py     #Модуль, после тщетной попытки создания класса в котором возникла проблема. 
    |  (ссылка ниже)    #Планировался как код модуля пользователей программы, в котором должен был быть 
    |                   #центральный класс AQUserSystem (род. MainWindow) (с экземпляром в основном коде) 
    |                   #и другие классы, наследуемые от него.
    |                   #Однако я обнаружил, что я не могу создать экземпляр этого класса (ошибка 
    |                   #ImportError: name 'MainWindow is not defined' при инициализации модуля 
    |                   #asQammUsers). Если я изменю в коде последнего `import AsQamm` на `from AsQamm 
    |                   #import MainWindow`, интерпретатор скажет, что круговой импорт.
    |                   # ~~Да, я в ООП у Python что-то всегда не понимал. Надо ещё подучить это~~
    |
AsQamm.py     # Ядро приложения. Конструктор класса MainWindow создаёт экземпляр класса Ui_MainWindow,
(ссылка ниже) # затем должен был создавать экземпляр AQUserSystem, затем - выполнять несколько методов
              # по первоначальной настройке интерфейса (привязка кнопок и инициализатор анимации меню 
              # (UIFunctions.toggleSimpleWidgetInteraction и UIFunctions.createLabels)).
```

---

### Ссылки на файлы

`_asQamm\asQammUI.py` - [тык](https://pastebin.com/mdeY6t9t). Осторожно! 1249 строк!
`_asQamm\asQammFunctions.py` - [тык](https://pastebin.com/yvnigTbi)
`_asQamm\asQammUsers.py`     - [тык](https://pastebin.com/qZF2SL3j)
`AsQamm.py`                  - [тык](https://pastebin.com/6kvuVEiW)
`resources.qrc` - [тык](https://pastebin.com/G7c7H3mY)

Также для запуска приложения потребуeтся папка images: [скачать архив](https://mega.nz/file/K4MU0Y4T#QH9FVZDIlI3xdr3GrYluMw-RPbmo_7rAcfiFxRhtDi8). разархивируйте в корень программы.

---

### Стактрейсы

#### В текущем состоянии

```py
  File "G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\AsQamm.py", line 9, in <module>
    import _asQamm.asQammUsers as aqUsers
  File "G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\_asQamm\asQammUsers.py", line 1, in <module>
    import AsQamm
  File "G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\AsQamm.py", line 10, in <module>
    import _asQamm.asQammFunctions as aqFunctions
  File "G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\_asQamm\asQammFunctions.py", line 5, in <module>
    class UIFunctions(MainWindow):
NameError: name 'MainWindow' is not defined.
```

#### Если строку 1 в модуле asQammUsers заменить на `from AsQamm import MainWindow`

```py
  File "G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\AsQamm.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _asQamm.asQammUsers import *
  File "G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\_asQamm\asQammUsers.py", line 1, in <module>
    import AsQamm
  File "G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\AsQamm.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _asQamm.asQammFunctions import *
  File "G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\_asQamm\asQammFunctions.py", line 1, in <module>
    from AsQamm import MainWindow
ImportError: cannot import name 'MainWindow' from partially initialized module 'AsQamm' (most likely due to a circular import) (G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\AsQamm.py)
```

Comment: Он не может найти ```MainWindow```, вы точно его импортировади в  файле *asQammFunctions.py*?

Comment: Да, это можно увидеть в первой строке этого файла.

Comment: Зачем, например, `UIFunctions` наследуется от `MainWindow`? Причина проблем как раз в этом. Это наследование совсем ни к чему.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, а как, по вашему, должны исполняться методы родительского класса? Все методы, объявленные в `UIFunctions` (приведите любой пример), требуют непосредственного доступа к `self` класса `MainWindow`. Без наследования функционирование этого класса невозможно!

Comment: UIFunctions вообще не должен быть наследником. Наследование нужно только в случае, когда нужно чтобы экземпляры наследника можно было использовать в контекстах, где ожидается родитель. Сами пишете, что из UIFunctions вообще экземпляры создаваться не будут. Это какойто утилитный клас. Его методы которые работают с экземпляром `MainWindow` просто должны его получать в параметре (сейчас собственно так и просходит, надо только название параметра поменять с `self` на `mainWindow`), а наследование вообще не нужно. Замена родителя c `MainWindow` на `object` никак не повредит функциональности класса.

Comment: Методы `UIFunctions` по сути своей статические, и должны быть объявлены таковыми.

Comment: Удивительно, но мне удалось найти другое решение этой задачи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Перестройте компонент `AsQamm.py`.** Сейчас все методы, которые осуществляются с `MainWindow`, вызываются в конструкторе этого класса. Для выполнения этих методов необходимы модули, отсылающие при инициализации обратно к классу `MainWindow`. таким, образом, образовалась парадоксальная ситуация: *для того, чтобы инициализировать класс* `MainWindow`, *необходима функциональность из внешних модулей, однако для инициализации этих модулей необходимо инициализировать родительский класс*.
2. Наследование класса `UIFunctions` действительно не имеет смысла. Переопределите атрибуты методов с `self` на `root`.

Решение:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from _asQamm.asQammUI import *
from _asQamm.asQammResources import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

from _asQamm.asQammUsers import *
from _asQamm.asQammFunctions import *


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = MainWindow()

    UIFunctions.createLabelsAtMainMenu(root)


    # Добавляем привязки клавиш к анимациям
    root.ui.btn_Toggle.clicked.connect(lambda: UIFunctions.toggleSimpleWidgetInteraction(root, 190, 1))
    root.ui.btn_DefnToggleCamList.toggled.connect(lambda: UIFunctions.toggleSimpleWidgetInteraction(root, 320, 2))

    # Cкин Дом
    root.ui.btn_page1.clicked.connect( lambda: UIFunctions.selectSkin(1) )

    # Скин Защита
    root.ui.btn_page2.clicked.connect( lambda: UIFunctions.selectSkin(2) )

    # Скин Растения
    root.ui.btn_page3.clicked.connect( lambda: UIFunctions.selectSkin(3) )

    # Скин Управление
    root.ui.btn_page4.clicked.connect( lambda: UIFunctions.selectSkin(4) )

    # Скин Конфигурации
    root.ui.btn_page5.clicked.connect( lambda: UIFunctions.selectSkin(5) )

    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

Я отметил строки которые поменял

**AsQamm.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

 
from _asQamm.asQammUI import *

#from _asQamm.asQammResources import *
# добавил в asQammUI.py  -> import resources_rc                           # !!!

import _asQamm.asQammUsers as aqUsers                        

#import _asQamm.asQammFunctions as aqFunctions
from _asQamm.asQammFunctions import  UIFunctions                          # !!!
 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
 
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
###
        self.uiFunctions = UIFunctions(self)                               # +++
 
#        aqFunctions.UIFunctions.createLabelsAtMainMenu(self)
        self.uiFunctions.createLabelsAtMainMenu()            # ? - self
 
        # Добавляем привязки клавиш к анимациям    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.ui.btn_Toggle.clicked.connect(lambda: self.uiFunctions.toggleSimpleWidgetInteraction(190, 1))            # - self, 
        #                                                     vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.ui.btn_DefnToggleCamList.toggled.connect(lambda: self.uiFunctions.toggleSimpleWidgetInteraction(320, 2)) # - self, 
 
# Cкин Дом  selectSkin () отсутствует 1 обязательный позиционный аргумент: 'self
#        self.ui.btn_page1.clicked.connect( lambda: aqFunctions.UIFunctions.selectSkin(1) )
        self.ui.btn_page1.clicked.connect( lambda: self.uiFunctions.selectSkin(1) )
 
        # Скин Защита
#        self.ui.btn_page2.clicked.connect( lambda: aqFunctions.UIFunctions.selectSkin(2) )
        self.ui.btn_page2.clicked.connect( lambda: self.uiFunctions.selectSkin(2) )
 
        # Скин Растения
#        self.ui.btn_page3.clicked.connect( lambda: aqFunctions.UIFunctions.selectSkin(3) )
        self.ui.btn_page3.clicked.connect( lambda: self.uiFunctions.selectSkin(3) )
 
        # Скин Управление                          vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.ui.btn_page4.clicked.connect( lambda: self.uiFunctions.selectSkin(4) )       #  !
 
        # Скин Конфигурации                        vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.ui.btn_page5.clicked.connect( lambda: self.uiFunctions.selectSkin(5) )       #  !
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = MainWindow()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**asQammFunctions.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                  # +++
from PyQt5.Qt import *                                      # +++  QPropertyAnimation


#from AsQamm import MainWindow                              # ---
import AsQamm                                               # +++

import json


 
#class UIFunctions(MainWindow):
class UIFunctions(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                                   # +++  
        super(UIFunctions, self).__init__(parent)                                      # +++
        self.parent = parent                                                           # +++
 
    def createLabelsAtMainMenu(self):
#       self.parent.ui. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        self.parent.ui.hintsSizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.parent.ui.styleSheet = str('''QLabel { font: 12pt "Segoe UI Semibold"; color: white; }
        QLabel:hover { color: rgb(47, 105, 23); }''')
 
#       self.parent.ui. 
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent = self.parent.ui.frame_top_menus)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint1.setText('Наш дом')
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint1.setStyleSheet(self.parent.ui.styleSheet)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint1.setSizePolicy(self.parent.ui.hintsSizePolicy)
 
        self.parent.ui.cel_TopMenuBtn1.addWidget(self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint1)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint1.hide()
 
 
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent = self.parent.ui.frame_top_menus)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint2.setText('Защита')
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint2.setStyleSheet(self.parent.ui.styleSheet)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint2.setSizePolicy(self.parent.ui.hintsSizePolicy)
 
        self.parent.ui.cel_TopMenuBtn2.addWidget(self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint2)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint2.hide()
 
 
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent = self.parent.ui.frame_top_menus)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint3.setText('Растения')
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint3.setStyleSheet(self.parent.ui.styleSheet)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint3.setSizePolicy(self.parent.ui.hintsSizePolicy)
 
        self.parent.ui.cel_TopMenuBtn3.addWidget(self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint3)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint3.hide()
        
 
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent = self.parent.ui.frame_top_menus)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint4.setText('Оборудование')
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint4.setStyleSheet(self.parent.ui.styleSheet)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint4.setSizePolicy(self.parent.ui.hintsSizePolicy)
 
        self.parent.ui.cel_TopMenuBtn4.addWidget(self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint4)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint4.hide()
        
 
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent = self.parent.ui.frame_top_menus)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint5.setText('Конфигурация')
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint5.setStyleSheet(self.parent.ui.styleSheet)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint5.setSizePolicy(self.parent.ui.hintsSizePolicy)
 
        self.parent.ui.cel_TopMenuBtn5.addWidget(self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint5)
        self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint5.hide()
 
 
    # Функция toggleSimpleWidgetInteraction может быть использована для анимирования виджетов простой
    # линейной анимацией. Ей необходимо иметь следующие аргументы: желаемый максимальный размер
    # виджета (ширина/высота в зависимости от типа анимации) и ID виджета, с которым она будет
    # работать.
 
    def toggleSimpleWidgetInteraction(self, maxLength, widgetId):
 
        maxExtend = int()
 
        if widgetId == 1: # проверяем аргумент на 1 вариант
 
            # получаем ширину фрейма 
            width = self.parent.ui.frame_left_menu.width()
            maxExtend = maxLength
            standard = 60
 
            # установим максимальное значение ширины фрейма
            if width == 60:
                lengthExtended = maxExtend
                self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint1.show()
                self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint2.show()
                self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint3.show()
                self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint4.show()
                self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint5.show()
 
            else:
                lengthExtended = standard
                self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint1.hide()
                self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint2.hide()
                self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint3.hide()
                self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint4.hide()
                self.parent.ui.lbl_MenuHint5.hide()
 
            # выполним горизонтальную анимацию
            
            self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.parent.ui.frame_left_menu, b"minimumWidth")
            self.animation.setDuration(200)
            self.animation.setStartValue(width)
            self.animation.setEndValue(lengthExtended)
            self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
            self.animation.start()
 
            self.animation2 = QPropertyAnimation(self.parent.ui.frame_top_menus, b"minimumWidth")
            self.animation2.setDuration(200)
            self.animation2.setStartValue(width)
            self.animation2.setEndValue(lengthExtended)
            self.animation2.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
            self.animation2.start() 
 
            
        elif widgetId == 2: # проверяем второй вариант
 
            height = self.parent.ui.tbw_DefnCamList.height()
            maxExtend == maxLength
            standard = 43
 
            # установим максимальное значение высоты фрейма и скроем/отобразим мешающие
            # элементы
            if height == 43:
 
                self.parent.ui.lbl_DefnCurrSetCamId.hide()
                self.parent.ui.lbl_ReadOnly10.hide()
                self.parent.ui.gvf_DefnCamView.hide()
 
            else:
 
                self.parent.ui.lbl_DefnCurrSetCamId.show()
                self.parent.ui.lbl_ReadOnly10.show()
                self.parent.ui.gvf_DefnCamView.show()
 
 
#    def selectSkin(id, self):
    def selectSkin(self, id):                    ###################################
        print(f'def selectSkin(self, id): {id}')
        if id == 1:
 
            self.parent.ui.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.parent.ui.page_1)
            self.parent.ui.lbl_SkinName.setText('Наш дом')
 
        elif id == 2:
 
            self.parent.ui.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.parent.ui.page_2)
            self.parent.ui.lbl_SkinName.setText('Защита')
 
        elif id == 3:
 
            self.parent.ui.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.parent.ui.page_3)
            self.parent.ui.lbl_SkinName.setText('Растения')
 
        elif id == 4:
 
            self.parent.ui.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.parent.ui.page_4)
            self.parent.ui.lbl_SkinName.setText('Управление')
 
        elif id == 5:
 
            self.parent.ui.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.parent.ui.page_5)
            self.parent.ui.lbl_SkinName.setText('Конфигурация')
```

**asQammUI.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
 
 
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

    ...

# +++        
import resources_rc    # +++


 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]